# lifetime of std::string passed as argument

Tags: c++, stl

I want to be sure I understand correctly.  In the c++ functions below three instances of
std::string will be created:

- one for s1 in caller() via what I believe is called the assignment constructor
- one for the s2 parameter of the callee() function via it's copy constructor
- one for s3 via its copy constructor

Am I correct?  And if so will all three instances be cleaned up as they go out of scope?  I'm not really asking if this is good code or not, just if my understanding is correct.

```
void caller(void) {
    std::string s1 = "hi";
    callee(s1);
}

void callee(std::string s2) {
    std::string s3 = s2;
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an "assignment constructor" as far as I know.  You have a "conversion constructor", which converts from one type to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost correct.

Either three or four strings may be created (depending on whether the construction of `s1` is elided), and in each case a constructor is called to construct them. Despite appearances, there are no calls to any assignment operators.

```
void caller(void) {
    //A temporary std::string is constructed with the
    //basic_string(const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())
    //constructor.
    //(In the call, `s` is initialized to point to the first element of "hi".)
    //This temporary is then move constructed in to s1.
    //The move constructor is
    //basic_string(basic_string&& other)
    //This move construction may be elided.
    std::string s1 = "hi"; //At the end of the full expression (ie, at the semicolon)
                           //the lifetime of the temporary string ends (unless
                           //the construction of s1 is elided, in which
                           //case the temporary becomes s1, and its lifetime ends
                           //with s1).
    //s2 is copy constructed from s1
    //The copy constructor is
    //basic_string(const basic_string& other)
    callee(s1);
    //the lifetime of s1 ends
}

void callee(std::string s2) {
    //s3 is copy constructed from s2
    std::string s3 = s2;
    //the lifetime of s3 ends
    //the lifetime of s2 ends
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't assume copies are made everywhere they *seem* to be made. In practice, copy-elision occurs more often than you'd think. Compilers are free to optimize away extra copies, even if the copy has a side-effect:

```
void caller(void) {
    std::string s1 = "hi";
    //theoretically, s1 is copied here
    //in practice, the compiler will optimize the call away
    functionCallee(s1);
}

void callee(std::string s2) {
    //although s2 is passed by value, it's probably no copy was created
    //most likely, it's exactly the same as s1 from the calling context
    std::string s3 = s2;
}
```

Moreover, if the methods are inline and the compiler detects no side-effects occur, the strings *might* not even be created.

Comment: Thanks!  So no memory leak doing it the way I illustrated?

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick there never is a memory leak if you never use `new` or `malloc`.

Comment: @Mankarse s2 is passed by value, so theoretically a copy is created inside `callee`. But it probably isn't.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: That doesn't explain how copy-elision can apply. `caller` has no idea if `functionCallee` will modify the argument in-place. Granted, `caller` does know that it won't be using `s1` anymore, and thus it **may** elide the copy. But it's very easy to stop copy elision by simply using the argument again.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not saying it will, but that it might and it's probable.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: "there never is a memory leak if you never use new or malloc." Nonsense. Even if you convert every pointer into `shared_ptr` with `make_shared`, you can *still* leak memory via circular references. Don't go thinking that you're memory-leak-proof just because you don't call `new` directly.

Comment: @NicolBolas I never said **directly**. :| If you call some method that calls `new` internally, of course you can leak...

Comment: @Luchian pretty much all C++ code will indirectly call `new`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `[class.copy]/31` states that construction can be elided in any of the following cases: when returning an automatic object, when throwing an exception, when constructing from a temporary, and when catching an exception. Which of these do you think applies?

Comment: @Mankarse I urge you to compile that code as-is, with full optimization and tell me how many strings are created.

Comment: @Mankarse also, not that copy elision can be applied in the cases you enumerated, but it's not limited to those. The compiler is free to make any sort of optimizations.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Of course the compiler can optimise code; however, optimisations never have any impact on the meaning of the code, so there is no need to mention them when answering a question about the meaning of some code. _copy elision_, on the other hand, is a way in which the meaning of code _can_ be different with different compilers. Labeling things that are simply optimisations as "copy elision" dilutes the meaning of the term, and can lead to confusion about the ways in which code can legally be optimised, where no confusion is necessary.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore (or anyone else who cares to contribute): In my real world case (which caused me to ask the question) the callee() function is a member function of a class and the s3 variable is actually a member variable in that class.  I *want* it to be a separate copy, not somehow "linked" to s1 in caller() which could possibly go out of scope before the object does.  I hope I've stated that clearly.  Will the compiler detect that that is my intention and make s3 a separate copy as I wish?

Comment: @JohnFitzpatrick of course. No need to worry. If your member is not a reference, it will outlive the variable it's assigned from.